# Date fiter query in mongoid with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, date, mongoid

I am using `mongodb(Mongoid)` and `rails 3.`

I have a field `"timestamp": ISODate("2013-02-07T04: 41: 52.773Z").`

Now i want to search date in range means fromdate and todate variables.

Value of `fromdate: "2013-02-01" and todate: "2013-02-08".`

I am trying using  `where(:timestamp.gt => fromdate, :timestamp.lt => todate)` but not get proper output.

How i can make a query to find data in date range..???

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert your "2013-02-01" to a Date object in Ruby. See http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html#M000215